# Uninstall all Avira programs/modules via the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, uninstall, avira

I'd first like to explain why I need to uinstall Avira and all of it's elements via the command line: Quite simply I need to do a bulk uninstall of 50 or so computers and doing that by hand is out of the question. Hence me wanting to do it from the command line, so I can throw it into a batch file and have that run on all computers.

Now I did find the command to uninstall the antivirus: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Avira\Antivirus\setup.exe" /remsilent` (or `/remsilentnoreboot` if I don't want to reboot)

But doing that still leaves the launcher behind. And I can't find the launcher's setup exe. So I'm kinda lost on what to do.

If there's more to remove or uninstall I'd like to know too as I want to make sure there are no remnants.

Comment: Did you check whether Avira have an uninstaller script? Pulling out an antivirus is often not a simple task, as they are especially resistant to that. It's their job.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes I searched the file system and looked for documentation online. They always just tell to use the ``setup.exe``. But as mentioned that clearly isn't enough.